# Can I assign a variable to the result of an if statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, variable-assignment

I am just wondering, is there a way to assign a variable to the result of an `if` statement. Would something like this be allowed in javascript?

```
var result = if (someVariable === 2) { 
  return something; 
} else if (someOtherVariable) {
  return somethingElse;
} else { return null; }
```

Where `result` would end up being equal to whatever the if statement returns. Also, if this is not allowed in JS, is it allowed in other languages (just out of curiosity)?

Comment: See use of a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), e.g., `var result = someVariable === 2 ? something : {something else, including potentially another ternary operation}; `

Comment: Thanks @sinaraheneba! Is there a way to have it work for three options?

Comment: Yes, the false expression can include another ternary operation. Scroll down to 'conditional chains' on the linked page for an example.

Comment: That said, nested conditionals is pretty hard to read, it's generally not recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the ? operator.

```
var result = (someVariable === 2 ? something : (someOtherVariable ? somethingElse : null));
```

The operator works like this:

boolean ? result if true : result if false;

Comment: Just cleaning up some old posts, and I realised I hadn't accepted this answer.